# Date Picker getting clipped if theme is applied to device

Tags: android, datepicker

I created Date Picker in my app using Android developer link [Android Date Picker](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html).

But when I click on button to show date picker, date picker is visible but  it is getting clipped from top, here is the screenshot of the same.[image: Date Picker Screen shot]

As from the image it is clearly visible that 27 is getting clipped and not visible properly.This issue comes when I apply **theme on my device** and doesn't happen when I use the default theme. What steps can be taken to make the view visible properly in case of custom themes.

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: It's same as from the link

Comment: did you try on emulator or real device?

Comment: tried on real device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say what is the problem, but I use this code and it works fine.

Define globally

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

in onCreate():

```
 //showing calendar for dob
    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateset = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            updateLabel();

        }

    };


    //assuming dob is your textView to select date
    dob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(Signup.this, dateset, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });
```

outside onCreate, new function

```
 private void updateLabel() {

    String myFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

    dob.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: This is an alternate solution to the problem not a proper one. Moreover I have used the same code dozen of times before an never had this issue before

Comment: are you using any custom font or theme in your device?

Comment: yes I am using theme in my device which provides it's own font

Comment: I think that might be causing trouble.. better you try once by removing the theme

Comment: You are right!!. It is the problem with the theme, I revert to the default theme and now it is showing properly